# Android changing webview

Tags: android, angularjs, webview

I'm trying to change my webview page by using script language. I can load a page only once, but when I try to load another one, it doesnt really change.
Here is the code:

WebView myWebView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    loadPage("reconhecimento");
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //Configuração do ZOOM
    //myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    //myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    myWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this,"Android");
}

 @JavascriptInterface
 public void loadPage(String page){
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+page+".html");
 }
```

So, when I send the variable trough Angularjs, it should change the webview page, but it doesn't. Anyone knows why?

Edit: This is how my folders looks like:
[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lVLs.png)

Edit2: This is how my angular and html looks li

```
app.controller("speechController", function($scope){
    $scope.speech = 'teste';
    $scope.page = 'index';
    $scope.talk = function(){
        Android.askSpeechInput();
    }
    $scope.listen = function(speech){
        Android.onSpeak(speech);
    }
    $scope.url = function(page){
        Android.loadPage(page);
    }
});
```

html:

```
<body  ng-controller="speechController">
    <div class="speech-container">
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn bg-pink-400 btn-block" ng-click="talk()">Pressione para falar... <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn bg-pink-400 btn-block" ng-click="listen(speech)">Pressione para ouvir... <i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn bg-pink-400 btn-block" ng-click="url(page)">Index
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Edit 3: I created a class to implement the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, however it still doesnt work:

```
class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: how are you calling loadPage ?

Comment: Just edited, Im calling loadPage both in java and angularjs, however once it loads the first time, it doesn't load the second.

Comment: I think you will need the function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to override your current url

Comment: Steven, Might be the way I'm calling the function, but still won't work.

Comment: I realized that the shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesn't really change the URL, only makes it so that when you open a link, it wont be opened by your default browser.